# Trying to login to site with PHP & cURL?

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I've never done something like this before...I'm trying to log into swagbucks.com and get retrieve some information, but it's not working. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my script?

```
<?php
$pages = array('home' =>
'http://swagbucks.com/?cmd=home',
           'login' =>
'http://swagbucks.com/?cmd=sb-login&from=/?cmd=home',
           'schedule' =>
'http://swagbucks.com/?cmd=sb-acct-account&display=2');
$ch = curl_init();
//Set options for curl session
$options = array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; `rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6',`
         CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
         //CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
         CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
         CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt');


//Hit home page for session cookie
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['home'];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);

//Login
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['login'];
$options[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE;
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = 'emailAddress=lala@yahoo.com&pswd=jblake&persist=on';
$options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = FALSE;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);

//Hit schedule page
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['schedule'];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$schedule = curl_exec($ch);

//Output schedule
echo $schedule;

//Close curl session
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But it still doesn't log me in. What's wrong?

Comment: You might want to censor your personal information.

Comment: +1 for not giving us real credentials

Comment: Maybe they are checking the http referer header if you are coming from their login form? So, try to add that header as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to echo each request to see if something went wrong.
(enabling CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and found I was requesting the wrong file...whoops.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/dev/null');
```

This way cookies are stored internally in-memory without the need of a separated file.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with  "persist=1" , not "persist=on" :

```
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = 'emailAddress=lala@yahoo.com&pswd=jblake&persist=on'; // doesn't work
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = 'emailAddress=lala@yahoo.com&pswd=jblake&persist=1'; // works
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = 'emailAddress=lala@yahoo.com&pswd=jblake'; // also works
```